# Spring core compatibilty issues with security and aop

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is there a specific version of spring core that is compatible with spring security and aop?

I tried these version but still getting error

```
org.springframework version : 4.0.3.RELEASE
org.springframework.security version : 3.2.0.RELEASE
error : missing CompositeUriComponentsContributor


org.springframework version : 4.0.3.RELEASE
org.springframework.security version : 4.0.3.RELEASE
error : missing AnnotationConfigRegistry


org.springframework version : 4.2.2.RELEASE
org.springframework.security version : 4.0.1.RELEASE
error : missing CorsProcessor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference documentation of Spring Security 4.0.4 [states](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven):

> Spring Security builds against Spring Framework 4.2.5.RELEASE, but
>   should work with 4.0.x.

Releases of Spring Security are not aligned with releases of Spring Framework.

However, dependencies `spring-core` and `spring-aop` (both belonging to Spring Framework) should **always** be the same version.